# Is it possible to back up data in this situation?

Tags: backup, boot-loop

I want to backup data from my phone currently in bootloop

The current situation:

- phone - LG V40 ThinQ
- Android Pie
- **rooted** with Magisk
- **unlocked** bootloader
- USB debugging **enabled**
- fastboot mode working (possible access with working commands from cmd)
- EDL mode working (PC recognize device)
- stock recovery mode working (but PC don't recognize device in this mode and adb commands don't work)
- bootlooped after manually reboot after modifications with YouTube system app

In this case there are any chances to repair from bootloop, most importantly, to backup photo and video data?

Comment: Have you tried to boot a boot a recovery like TWRP via fastboot? You phone should be old enough so that it may work and hopefully the recovery has decryption support. there doesn't seem to be an official TWRP recovery for your device but that doesn't mean you can not find one on XDA.

Comment: @Robert thank you for fast response. I was wondering about flashing TWRP, because it seems to be the only option to use adb commands. I'm just afraid that if it fails, the phone will be bricked twice - not only will I have a problem with the system application, but also a problem with custom recovery. Then I won't even know what exactly is bootlooping it, so recovering from the situation will be harder. However, if there are no major contraindications and better alternatives, maybe I should take advantage of this. What do you think?

Comment: Your phone should support to directly boot a recovery from image file without flashing it.

Comment: shameless self-promotion, you can use my [script](https://gitlab.com/aIecxs/adb_pull_junks/-/blob/main/adb_pull_junks.sh) to copy files, just need to adjust junk size to fit the time gap between reboots

Comment: Thank you guys in this mentally difficult moment for me. As in general digital values are less important to me, here are the only recent photos of my beloved dog, who recently passed away. If I understand Robert correctly, probably I can open (boot) TWRP, not install (flash) it? That would be safer in case of failure. alecxs, sorry for my noob question, but is your program running even before TWRP boot? Since booting occurs during normal boot for me - safe modes work fine (though without access to adb commands). Also, can it be used on Win? Thank you for your help during this difficult time.

Comment: if you can boot in safe mode then you can backup everything to MicroSD card, can't you?